# JAVA fx 8 List View Update

Tags: java, listview, javafx-8

Hi i have a Problem i want to update a ListView with int values out of my ArrayList and update it everytime a value changes. It seems Simple but im realy stuck and read about 3hrs in the Web already. Heres my code if it helps.

This is where i add data to my listview:

```
   public void setQuizModel(QuizModel model)
{

    this.quizModel = model;

    // this.antworten.bind(this.quizModel.getrichtigvalue());
    for (int i = 0; i < this.quizModel.getQuiz().size(); i++)
    {
        this.view.fillList("1. " + this.quizModel.getQuiz().get(i).getFragen() + " (Antworten: " + this.quizModel.getOAnswearlist().get(this.quizModel.getNumberq()) + ", davon richtig:" + this.quizModel.getORightlist().get(this.quizModel.getNumberq()) + " )");
    }

}
```

My lists:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> antworten = new ArrayList<>();

private ObservableList<Integer> oantworten = FXCollections.observableArrayList(this.antworten);

private ArrayList<Integer> richtig = new ArrayList<>();

private ObservableList<Integer> orichtig = FXCollections.observableArrayList(this.richtig);

private ArrayList<Quiz> quizcollection = new ArrayList<>();
```

thats how i fill them:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < this.quizcollection.size(); i++)
    {
        this.oantworten.add(new Integer(0));
        this.orichtig.add(new Integer(0));
    }
```

And so one of the values inside the list gets changed and i want to update listview(i thought it would happen automaticly through the observerbale list)

```
  public void richtigincrement()
{
    this.orichtig.add(this.numberq, this.orichtig.get(this.numberq).intValue() + 1);
}

public void antwortincrement()
{

    this.oantworten.add(this.numberq, this.oantworten.get(this.numberq).intValue() + 1);

}
```

Ty very much for all help
EDIT:
the view.filllist is called in the view class to fill the list 

    `public void fillList(String e)
    {
        this.list.getItems().add(e);
    }`

Heres the code of the 3 classes wich are needed http://pastebin.com/iDxuK0nk
the Problem is to define it exactlier.
Its a Quiz with 4 radio buttons everytime i make an answear he should save how often i tried to answear that question and how often it was right.
2 Arrays or Observ.Lists 1 for the total answears on the question and 1 for the right answears on that question.
And if i click on overview i see this values, but the problem is he didnt change the values he get out of the arrays in the listview if they change.

Comment: Use only observable list if you can, drop usage of arraylists. Where is your listview, I cannot see it in the code? How the view.fillList looks like?

Comment: please provide a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem